# Python - Dice Simulator

Tags: python

This is my homework question:

> Write a program that simulates rolling a set of six-sided dice multiple times. The program should use a dictionary to record the results and then display the results.
>
> Input: The program should prompt for the number of dice to roll and the number of times to roll the dice.
>
> Output:
>
> The program is to display how many times each possible value was rolled. The format of the output must be as shown below:
>
> The first column is the number shown on the dice when they are rolled. The brackets are only as wide as needed and the number inside the brackets is right justified. Note the minimum and maximum values in the sample runs below.
>
> The second column is the number of times that value was rolled. This column is right justified.
>
> The last column is the percent of times that the number was rolled. The percentages are displayed with an accuracy of one decimal place.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import random
from math import floor, ceil
one = 0
two = 0
three = 0
four = 0
five = 0
six = 0
rand = float(0)
rolltotal = int(input("How many times do you want to roll? "))    
q = 0    
while q < rolltotal:
    q = q + 1
    rand = ceil(6*(random.random()))
    if rand == 1:    
        one = one + 1
    elif rand == 2:
        two = two + 1
    elif rand == 3:
        three = three + 1
    elif rand == 4:
        four = four + 1
    elif rand == 5:
        five = five + 1
    else:
        six = six + 1

total = one + two + three + four + five + six

print("[1]", one, " ",round(100*one/total, 1),"%")    
print("[2]", two, " ",round(100*two/total, 1),"%")
print("[3]", three, " ",round(100*three/total, 1),"%")
print("[4]", four, " ",round(100*four/total, 1),"%")
print("[5]", five, " ",round(100*five/total, 1),"%")    
print("[6]", six, " ",round(100*six/total, 1),"%")
```

My question is: I just know how to roll one dice. how can i get more than one .

Comment: You're doing great. You need to do the first part more than once, inside a loop (look up "control flow" or "for loop").

(And to get more advanced, see if there's a way to not need the six variables one, two, three, etc. Think of the question, "How hard would it be to change this to a 10-sided die, instead of a 6-sided one?")

Comment: You should read up about python [dictionaries](http://diveintopython.org/getting_to_know_python/dictionaries.html) since your homework assignment explicitly requires the use of them.

Comment: Note random() can return 0, so your ceil() is not quite right. Try using floor instead, see if you can get 1-6 with it.

Comment: actually you should use `random.randint(1,6)`

Comment: @GWW seems like he is using Python 3 here, so better link to dictionaries is: http://diveintopython3.org/native-datatypes.html#dictionaries

Comment: I also think that using [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) can even more simplify the code. In a fact, Counter is a dictionary, however it is possible that they just have to use the plain dictionaries....

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random

dice = int(input("How many dice do you want to roll? "))
rolls = int(input("How many times do you want to roll them? "))

irange = xrange
sides = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

d = defaultdict(int)
for r in irange(rolls):
    d[sum( random.choice(sides) for d in irange(dice) )] += 1

total = float(rolls)
for k in sorted(d.keys()):
    print "[%d] %d %.1f%%" % (k, d[k], 100.0*d[k]/total)
```

Comment: whoever named `xrange` didn't follow itertools' naming. and `irange` fits in with `imap`, `izip` considering that they are the iterator returning versions of `range`, `map`, and `zip`.

Comment: Thats why xrange isn't in the itertools module.

Comment: from collections import defaultdict
import random

dice = int(input("How many dice do you want to roll? "))
rolls = int(input("How many times do you want to roll them? "))

sides = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

d = defaultdict(int)
for r in range(rolls):
    d[sum( random.choice(sides) for d in range(dice) )] += 1

total = float(rolls)
for k in sorted(d.keys()):
    print ("[%d] %d %.1f%%" % (k, d[k], 100.0*d[k]/total))

Comment: @Dan D. If it's homework, why did you provide working code? Just give him advice and let him solve it himself...

Comment: If you turn that in, your teach **will** give you an F. Just a warning. And not because @DanD. wrote bad code.

Answer (score -1):

You would rather do the following:-

```
loop=True
import random  #This allows python to import built in "random" function.
while loop is True:    
    dice=input("Which sided dice would you like to roll? (You can only choose 4,6 or 12) \n") # "\n" allows python to add a new line.
    if dice=="4":
         print("You have chosen to roll dice 4\nYour score is... \n", random.randint(1,4)) #This allows python to generate a random number from 1 to 4.
    elif dice=="6":
         print("You have chosen to roll dice 6\nYour score is...\n", random.randint(1,6)) #This allows python to generate a random number from 1 to 6.
    elif dice=="12":
        print("You have chosen to roll dice 12\nYour score is...\n", random.randint(1,12)) #This allows python to generate a random number from 1 to 12.
    else: print("Invalid option! Please try again!") 
    loop2=input("Do you want to roll again? (Yes or No) \n")
    if loop2=="yes" or loop2=="Yes": # "or" funtion allows python to accept any of the two answers input by the user.
       loop=True
    else: break    # This function allows program to close.
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the question, except being somehow related to dice.